# Which tables and columns are altered for both REVOKE/GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION

Tags: postgresql, privileges

Which tables/columsn are altered for the following queries:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "..."() FROM PUBLIC CASCADE;
-- function_owner can still update the function

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "..."() TO function_owner CASCADE;


REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "..."() FROM function_owner CASCADE;
-- function_owner can't update the function. 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "..."() TO function_owner CASCADE;
-- function_owner can now update the function.
```

I know that `pg_catalog.pg_proc.proacl` are altered. Are there any other tables and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_proc.proacl` is indeed the only column that is modified if you `GRANT` or `REVOKE` privileges on a function.

There are two things to keep in mind:

1. When a function is created, it has the default privileges (`PUBLIC` and the owner may `EXECUTE` it) and the `proacl` column is NULL (this signifies default privileges).

   That is why the column is empty in the beginning and contains a value after you `REVOKE` the privileges for `PUBLIC`.
2. If you `REVOKE` a privilege that hasn't been granted before, nothing happens. Similarly, if you `GRANT` a privilege that is already granted, nothing happens.

   Your `GRANT` is such a no-operation, because the owner has the `EXECUTE` privilege by default. You just don't see it before you changed the privilege from the default with your `REVOKE`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you learn all of this? Just by reading the docs? Or did you also read the source code too?

Comment: Reading the documentation, playing with the software, reading and hacking the source.

Comment: Any recommended reading on setting up (or altering) defaults for a newly created database? Or does the PG documentation pretty much cover it all?

Comment: I don't like that `PUBLIC` has the execute privileges by default, so I use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to change that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `GRANT` above, after the `REVOKE`, is not exactly a no-operation: Without it, the owner can't update the function. After the `GRANT`, the owner can update the function. So that is why I asked the original question, because something is being updated to allow the function owner to update it (even though I can't find what it is).

Comment: Oh wait.. I'm going to re-run the code to make sure. SOrry about that.

Comment: If I `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGS ON "function"(...) FROM function_owner CASCADE`, the proacl column is set to `NULL`. But, then when I run the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` to the function_owner, the column is set, and the role can update the column. So something else seems to be updated to prevent/allow updating the function, other than the `proacl`?

Comment: Ok. So I think I finally figured it out:  `proacl` is of type `_aclitem`.  It starts off as `NULL` (before any REVOKE/GRANT/DEFAULT PRIVILEGES). `REVOKE ... FROM PUBLIC` sets it to `{function_owner=X/function_owner}`.  `REVOKE ... FROM function_owner` sets it to an "empty" value: `{}`. And `GRANT ... function_owner` sets it back to `{function_owner=X/function_owner}`. So you are right: the `proacl` column is the only one that gets updated with 3 different values: NULL, empty _aclitiem, `{role=privileges}`. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Oh, you are right of course. Empty values and NULL look the same.